# Where/how to add d.ts for private, scoped npm modules?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8, typescript-typings

I am attempting to port a Javascript project to Typescript. I have a dependency named like: `@myscope/utils`

A file from this is imported into the ts file as follows:

```
import date = require('@myscope/utils/date');
```

When I attempt to compile this I get the following error:

```
src/subfolder/something.ts(12,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@myscope/utils/date'.
```

How do I add my own typings for private modules like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself. 
I referred to the information on [writing declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html)

The key to get the module to be resolved is to **declare a module with a name of the full path of the package**. I created a `index.d.ts` file for the module, that I added to my `files` section of `tsconfig.json`.

The file contained the following declaration:

```
declare namespace date {
  function now(): number;
}

declare module "@myscope/utils/date" {
   export = date; 
}
```

Though not necessary, I structured my imports like typings does. I may simplify later after I've ported the rest of the application.

I created the following files:

```
mytypings/index.d.ts
mytypings/modules/@myscope/utils/index.d.ts
```

Note there is no date part of the utils path.

`mytypings/index.d.ts` contains a reference path to `mytypings/modules/@myscope/utils/index.d.ts` and then was added to section of `tsconfig.json`.

My plan is to add other libraries in the same way.