# How to Setup VS Code For Creating TypeScript Definition Files

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have this current folder structure:

```
project
└───typings
│   |   index.d.ts
|   FileToMakeTdFor.js
|   FileToMakeTdFor-Tests.ts
```

where I have a JS file that I'm trying to make a Typescript Definition (d.ts)  for.

The js file looks like this:

```js
"use strict";
var FileToMakeTdFor = (function () {
    function FileToMakeTdFor(config) {
        ...
    }
    FileToMakeTdFor.prototype.example = function () {
        ...
    };
    return CRMWebAPI;
}());
exports.FileToMakeTdFor = FileToMakeTdFor;
```

The index.d.ts file looks like this:

```js
export interface FileToMakeTdFor {
    new (config:any): FileToMakeTdFor;
    example(): void;
}
```

And in my test file I'm attempting to write this:

```js
let obj = new FileToMakeTdFor();
obj.example();
```

But I get an error on the constructor `Cannot find name FileToMakeTdFor`

How do I make the test ts file find the index.d.ts file?  Is there a better way to setup this structure?

Comment: Does this help:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39237584/1575281
this was pre-2.0.0

Comment: if the code and the test code is compiled together there's no need to create definition files. it should work out of the box. your problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: In addition, how are you importing the `FileToMakeTdFor` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special thanks to Dave Hillier's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39237584/1575281).  It lead me to the TypeScript [Handbook for declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-class-d-ts.html).  Apparently I was just missing some export calls:

```js
/*~ If this module is a UMD module that exposes a global variable 'CRMWebAPI' when
 *~ loaded outside a module loader environment, declare that global here.
 *~ Otherwise, delete this declaration.
 */
export as namespace FileToMakeTdFor;

/*~ This declaration specifies that the class constructor function
 *~ is the exported object from the file
 */
export = FileToMakeTdFor;

export interface FileToMakeTdFor {
    new (config:any): FileToMakeTdFor;
    example(): void;
}
```

Once I added the `export as namespace FileToMakeTdFor;` and `export = FileToMakeTdFor;` lines, everything started working...