# How to provide TypeScript type declarations for modules whose name contains an '@'?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make the TypeScript compiler happy by providing type declaration (`.d.ts`) files for all my untyped dependencies. However, some of those are custom forks of popular packages, or packages like [these](https://github.com/absinthe-graphql/absinthe-socket) which are part of a larger project and share the same `@<project-name>` namespace. In those cases, their name will contain the `@` character and a slash, for example `@absinthe/socket`.

How do I declare my typed module in the `.t.ds` file in that case? For the above example, I tried `declare module '@absinthe/socket'` and `declare module 'absinthe__socket'` (as suggested by the TypeScript compiler), but neither worked.

Comment: This question looks very similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235931/where-how-to-add-d-ts-for-private-scoped-npm-modules

Comment: Thanks @artem, it does indeed! Turns out this syntax actually worked, I just had an incorrectly placed `import` in the declaration file (see my own answer below).

Answer (score 3):

Turned out I had incorrectly imported another module within my definition file, but outside the `declare module @absinthe/socket` scope. This led the TS compiler to treat the file as an implementation, not declaration file. Moving the import within the module declaration like so

```
declare module '@absinthe/socket' {
  import { Socket as PhoenixSocket } from 'phoenix'
  …
}
```

solved my issue. So in other words, the syntax `@absinthe/socket` works fine when declaring the type oneself within a `.d.ts` file. It is only when getting such a declaration from DefinitelyTyped (or another NPM source) that one needs to use the double underscore syntax (`absinthe__socket`).

Answer (score 0):

[Here's another question which describes how to install namespaced packages through @types.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296731/how-can-i-install-typescript-declarations-for-scoped-namespaced-packages-over-t)

> Unfortunately, npm doesn't permit scoped packages to contain @ in their name, so these names are mangled to use two underscores in place of the @.
>
> So specifically, if you want to install type declarations for the package @foo/bar, you'll need to run
>
> ```
> npm install @types/foo__bar
> ```

If they're not available for the packages you want, [make sure your `.d.ts` file is properly included under your tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html). e.g. If you have `"include": ["src/**/*"]`, make sure the `.d.ts` file is in the `src` folder.

Comment: Thank you @kingdaro! While my issue was about providing _local_ typings in a `.d.ts` file, this does bring useful information to the table for those who want to get typings via NPM instead.